# How do I sort digital photos and scans together in Lightroom 4?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-4, scanning

I have many images captured with a digital camera and many that I've scanned from negatives and stills. I use the `Edit Capture Date...` option to set the capture time of the scan. However, when I sort by capture date, the sorting is inconsistent between those that have the capture date in the EXIF data and those where I've set it manually (might be stored in EXIF as well). Any ideas about sorting these two types of images consistently?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Smart Collections" to automatically add images based on any field that you specify.
I suggest, tagging scanned prints as "negatives" or something and adding that to the Smart Collection using "Keywords"

Comment: I'd like to order the pictures in chronological order by capture date and have them be mixed in albums. I'm not sure how the use of smart collections helps. It's possible I'm not understanding you.